# switch-case pick up specific item in text based java game

Tags: java, arraylist, input, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I was developing a little text-based rpg in java and came across a difficult obstacle, that I can't find a solution for.

The game manager is a simple switch-case scanner that follows commands based on my input. I'd like to "equip items" by typing equip + the name of it. However I think there is a better solution than adding a case in my switch-case method. If I had 1000 items in my game, that would be 1000 cases to go through, there must be a better way right?

How do I look if my input contains the name of my item ArrayList in my item class?

```
static void UseCommands() {
        String input = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!input.equals("Close")) {
            input = sc.next();
            switch (input) {


            case "commands":
                PlayerActions.ShowCommands();
                break;    
            case "inventory":
                PlayerActions.ShowInventory();
                break;
            case "equipment":    
                PlayerActions.ShowEquipment();
                break;
            case "spawnItem":    
                Item.SpawnItem();
                break;
            case "addItem":

            case "close":
                sc.close();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add some code? It will help use guide through a solution

Comment: Added my code from the game manager class. Was thinking maybe a map in a new ItemDataBase class would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes in my mind would be to split the user input on a space character which will return an array of strings so you can keep your switch case on the array[0] with a  case "equip":.

Then you code your function equip to take a parameter wich would be array[1]. Just be sure the array returned by the split is at least 2 in length otherwise you will get IndexArrayOutOfBoundException.